# Reduce Cell of vectors according to some conditions

Tags: matlab, cell, knapsack-problem

Let `A` be a cell of vectors. For convenience let those vector be denoted as `V1`, `V2`,...

I want to find a maximum set of vectors that have no "coincidences". A coincidence between two vectors `Vn` and `Vm` occurs when any of these conditions hold:

- The two vectors have some common value, i.e. `Vn(i)==Vm(j)` for some `i`, `j`.
- The two vectors have two values that differ in `100`, i.e. `abs(Vn(i)-Vm(j))==100` for some `i`, `j`.

Example:

```
A = {[2 5],[8 9 2],[33 77 4],[102 6],[10 66 17 7],[110 99],[1 4 3],[15 41 88]}

Possible_Result = {[2 5],[33 77 4],[10 66 17 7],[15 41 88]}
```

In order not to complicate my problem, the choice of a result between several possible outcomes is not important.

Comment: Why do you remove `[102 6]`? It has no common values with other vectors

Comment: @LuisMendo: 102 = 100+2,  ([2 5])

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question for future reference. It's hard to understand as it stands

Comment: Very interesting problem.  The only way I can see you do this is by brute force (à la Luis Mendo).  BTW, this is a reformulation of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is a [NP-complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).  There is currently no polynomial-time algorithm that can solve this efficiently, so the most intuitive way to solve this would be brute force.  I hope your data set isn't huge, because these kinds of problems grow in exponential time as the data set gets large!

Comment: The very insightful comment by @rayryeng makes me think that my code may not be actually finding a maximum set. Perhaps the best way is "bruter"-force: test _all_ possible subsets to see if they fulfill your conditions. My approach is only "brute" in the sense of doing all pairwise comparisons, but not of testing all possible subsets

Comment: My solution is truly brute now: test all possible subsets for validity and pick one with maximum number of vectors. Please see edite answer. Thanks for the heads-up, @rayryeng!

Comment: @LuisMendo - You have already received my upvote :)  It is certainly a good answer!  You're welcome :)  When I see questions that do look difficult to solve, I check to see if the problem falls or can be reformulated into one of the problems from the [list of NP-Complete problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems).  If it does fall into one of these problems, I don't bother to answer.  It would take too much time to write an elegant answer.

Comment: @rayryeng I did know the knapsack problem, but I failed to see this was an instance of it. Anyway, I think my answer now finds a maximal subset; but of course in non-polynomial (actually exponential) time. One gets a strange inner satisfaction from using brute-force sometimes :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo - Basically, when it comes to choosing a subset of items that have an associated cost (in our case, it's `abs(Vn(i) - Vm(j))`) where it is our goal to minimize the total cost required to choose such items, it's an instance of the knapsack problem.  I will admit that it was a bit difficult to see this as an instance of that knapsack problem, but when I thought about it more, it certainly does!  If you did an even heavier reformulation, this could be classified as an instance of the [zero-sum subset problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), but let's not go that far!

Comment: @rayryeng Good intuition!

Comment: @rayryeng I've labelled the question accordingly. (I also had to rewrite it, as it was difficult to understand as originally stated)

Comment: @LuisMendo - That's a much better description.  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng Just one more question: is it still knapsack when the cost is per _pair_ of elements (not per each individual element)?

Comment: @LuisMendo - I would still say so.  Ultimately, you would choose an individual item based on looking at a pair of items.  The cost would be pairwise rather than individual.

Comment: @LuisMendo - I appreciate this discussion we are having :)  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng Same here! Very interesting! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force approach:

1. Determine "coincidences" between vectors, acccording to the rules in your question.
2. For each possible subset, test its validity by determining if there are coincidences between its vectors or not.
3. Among all valid subsets, pick one with the maximum number of vectors.

This is probably *slow*, mainly because it's brute-force (try all possible subsets), and secondarily because it uses `cellfun` and an anonymous function.

Memory usage is low, because each subset (specified by a vector of logical values) is defined on the fly. This relies on the fact that the set of all possible subsets can be enumerated, and the correspondence between subset number and subset description is just binary expansion.

```
%// STEP 1
%// Definition of "coincidence" between two vectors x and y:
f = @(x,y) nnz(ismember(bsxfun(@minus, x(:),y(:).'), [-100 0 100])); %' 
%// Generate all combinations:
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(A));
%// Test for each pair of vectors for coincidences:
M = cellfun(f, A(ii), A(jj)); %// m(k,l)>0 indicates coincidence betwen vectors k and l
M = triu(M,1); %// consider each pair only once; and disregard self-coincidences

%// STEP 2
%// Test if each subset is valid, using (part of) matrix M:
valid = ones(1,2^numel(A)); %// this will store whether each subset is valid
num = NaN(1,2^numel(A)); %// this will store number of vectors in each subset
for n = 1:2^numel(A) %// there are 2^numel(A) possible subsets
    s = logical(dec2bin(n-1)-'0'); %// 1: vector is present. 0: is absent
    num(n) = sum(s); %// number of vectors in the subset
    if nnz(M(s,s)) %// if there are coincidences...
        valid(n) = 0; %// ...then this subset is not valid
    end
end

%// STEP 3
%// Find *first* (in the order of ss) valid subset with maximum number of elements:
[~, t] = max(valid.*num); %'// (it'd be easy to output *all* maximum subsets)
A_solution = A(logical(dec2bin(t-1)-'0'));
```

Comment: if A = {[109 146],[111 142],[117 146],[117 154],[117 155]}; I get: {[109 146],[111 142]} !!! Normally the result should include [117 154] or [117 155].

Comment: @bzak You are right. I wasn't taking into account that once you remove an element, its coincidences with other elements should be removed as well. Please see edited answer

Comment: ???     [~, col] = find(m,1);
          |
Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: @bzak Which Matlab version do you use? Try `[val, col] = find(m,1);`

Comment: I use Matlab R2009a !

Comment: @bzak - Output variable suppression of functions (i.e. `~`) was only supported as of MATLAB R2009b.  You are unfortunately one version short of this (rather beautiful) syntax.  As such, use a dummy variable in place of the `~` and clear it when you're done (i.e. `val` as per Luis Mendo).

Comment: @LuisMendo: Thank you for the time you take to respond to my question!  I have a problem with the latest version: if numel(A) = 78, I can not use your answer and I get:??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> dec2bin at 58
s=char(rem(floor(d*pow2(1-max(n,e):0)),2)+'0');

Error in ==> ss = logical(dec2bin(0:2^numel(A)-1)-'0'); %// 1: vector is present. 0: is absent. I can use your answer only if numel(A)=21 and i get 4 vectors. But if I use the first version with numer(A)=78, i get 9 vectors!

Comment: @bzak That's the problem with brute-force (testing all possible subsets): it requires a lot of memory. I don't see what can be done about it.

Comment: @bzak Wait. I have an idea to reduce memory consumption

Comment: See (hopefully definitive) edit. It reduces memory usage by enumerating the subsets instead of pre-generating them. But be prepared for large running times, as @rayryeng said above

Comment: @LuisMendo: ??? Error using ==> ones
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Error in ==> valid = ones(1,2^numel(A)); %// this will store whether each subset is valid

Comment: @bzak - If `A` is of a moderate size (e.g. 25), you will quickly run out of memory, as `2^25` is larger than what the maximum array size that can be allocated to MATLAB can handle.

Comment: @LuisMendo: So, I think the best way to deal with this is to keep the first version of your code for size(A) large (>21), apply several different and random permutations on A, and take the result that has the largest size. Of course, we'll just get close to the desired result.